# Удобное использование ООП

Tags: c#

Моя проблема заключается в том, что у меня куча классов и в каждом из них я постоянно пишу одинаковый код, я не очень силён в virtual, abstract, protected и.т.д.
Мне нужно сделать методы дефолтными, я выделил на фото красным те методы, которые я не буду изменять, а жёлтым те методы, которые мне когда-то возможно понадобится изменить.
Я вообще не хочу их писать в коде, а просто как-то наследовать что-то, что решит мю проблему.

```
internal class AutoBow : IHack
    {
        private MacrosManager mm = new MacrosManager(new MacrosUpdater());
        private Work work = new Work();
        public Info info = new Info(false, "AutoBow", "Marcos", "The Better Bow Spammer.");
        public static Cfg cfg = new Cfg(new List<Line>
        {
            new Line("key", "TargetKey", "MouseRight"),
            new Line("bool", "UsePing", "true"),
            new Line("int", "Delay", "10"),
        });
        Info IInfo.Info { get => info; set => info = value; }
        Cfg IHack.Cfg { get => cfg; set => cfg = value; }
        void IHack.Enable()
        {
            info.Enable = true;
            mm.LoadMacros(work)
;
        }
        void IHack.Disable()
        {
            info.Enable = false;
            mm.UnLoadMacros(work);
        }
        private class Work : Macros
        {
            public override bool OnKeyDown(Key key, bool repeat)
            {
                if (key == (Key)cfg.Value("TarggetKey"))
                {
                    KeyDown(Key.MouseLeft);
                    Sleep(((bool)cfg.Value("UsePing") ? Config.config.ping : 0) + (int)cfg.Value("Delay"));
                    KeyUp(Key.MouseLeft);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кому интересно что у меня в IHack:

```
    public interface IHack : IInfo
    {
        Cfg Cfg { get; set; }
        void Enable();
        void Disable();        
    }
    public interface IInfo
    {
        Info Info { get; set; }
    }
```

Так же я использую C# 7.2

Comment: И в чем, собственно, у вас затруднения? Делайте нужные методы виртуальными, наследуйте класс, который можно сделать абстрактным, все, дальше в нужном классе переопределяйте через `override` нужные методы, делая в них нужную логику. Попробуйте для начала, а уж потом просите помощь.

Comment: То что используется более одного раза, выносится либо в абстракцию, либо в сервис. Абстракция - это грубо говоря базовый класс, сервис - это грубо говоря отдельный класс, используемый в нескольких местах. Если вы новичок, старайтесь не создавать классы в классах, это только усложняет архитектуру.